# What happens with a specific function name 'it'?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I was just wrestling with a Haskell error for an hour, and then traced it to the use of a specific function name `it`. Can someone explain why function names `fu` and `it` behave differently in the transcript below? Specifically, why does the type of `it` change when it is called?

```
λ> fu x = x + 1
λ> :t fu
fu :: Num a => a -> a
λ> fu 1
2
λ> :t fu
fu :: Num a => a -> a
λ> it x = x + 1
λ> :t it
it :: Num a => a -> a
λ> it 1
2
λ> :t it
it :: Num a => a
```

When ghci is started fresh, it reports that `it` is not in scope, so I do not think `it` should have any special meaning by default.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In GHCi, `it` is always bound to the last evaluated expression, and shadows its previous value:

```
Prelude> 2 + 3
5
Prelude> it
5
Prelude> 3 * 4
12
Prelude> it
12
```

In the beginning of the GHCi session, it's not defined.

Comment: Ok, that is weird, I thought all the ghci stuff begins with a colon `:`.  I can not even find the description of `it` in ghci using `:help`. This came up in the context of numerically solving a differential equation, and `it` felt like a nice name for a function to iterate over. :)

Comment: You can use `it` just fine in compiled code or as a local variable. It's only GHCi that gives it a special meaning.